# One hot input to softmax output in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, softmax

I have a neural network with one-hot m*n vectors as input, with rows representing categories, and columns representing position.

I want to train a network to output another (stochastic) vector with the same m*n shape at the output layer, with probabilities at each column summing to one. The idea would be to use a softmax final layer, but do I need to build each column separately and concatenate [like here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23614/keras-multiple-softmax-in-last-layer-possible/23636)? or is it possible to do this more simply in (e.g. one-liner) in Keras?

Comment: concatenate n different m batches of softmax neurons in the final layer, one for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model has an output shape of `(None, m, n)` and you want to compute the softmax over the second axis, you can simply use the [`softmax`](https://keras.io/activations/#softmax) activation method and pass the `axis` argument to it (in your case it must be `axis=1`):

```
from keras import activations

def the_softmax(axis):
    def my_softmax(x):
        return activations.softmax(x, axis=axis)
    return my_softmax

# sequential model
model.add(Dense(..., activation=the_softmax(1)))

# functional model
output = Dense(..., activation=the_softmax(1))(prev_layer_output)
```

Alternatively, if you would like to use it as an independent layer, you can use a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer and the backend `softmax` function:

```
from keras import backend as K

def the_softmax(axis):
    def my_softmax(x):
        return K.softmax(x, axis=axis)
    return my_softmax

# sequential model
model.add(Lambda(the_softmax(1)))

# functional model
output = Lambda(the_softmax(1))(prev_layer_output)
```

Comment: That's helpful thanks, can it be done in the sequential model, or only the functional api?

Comment: But I can't use it directly as output, I get this error: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("truediv_4:0", shape=(?, 5, 2), dtype=float32)

Comment: @carefullynamed sorry, I did not test my code. Apparently, you need to use the `activation` argument of layer. Now it can be used both in sequential and functional models.

Comment: Dense requires an additional argument (units), is the shape preserved by going through that?

Comment: @carefullynamed I just used `Dense` as an example. Whatever layer you use as the last layer, use this softmax activation on it.

Comment: @carefullynamed I just added another solution if you would like to use it as an independent layer and changed the function to accept arbitrary axis.